# Apache Solr Indexing from DIH

Tags: solr, dih

I have setup solr. my data-config.xml looks like below

```
    <dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:hsqldb:/temp/example/ex" user="sa" />
    <document name="products">
     <entity name="item" query="select NAME,BSIN from items">
        <field column="NAME" name="id" />
        <field column="BSIN" name="bsin" />

        <entity name="brands" query="select brandname from brand where                 bsin='${item.BSIN}'" transformer="TemplateTransformer">
            <field name="brand" column="BRAND" />
            <field name="cname" column="namedesc" template="${item.NAME}-${brands.BRAND}" />
        </entity>

       </entity>
    </document>
   </dataConfig>
```

bsin and brand are multivalued fields.Now Each NAME has many BSIN and for each BSIN there is  a brand name.
I want index should happen in this way:

Name1-Brand1
Name1-Brand2
Name2-Brand1  etc. I am using Terms Component for autocomplete.Kindly help me achieve this.

Thanks in advance for help.
Regards,
Pavan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting **rootEntity="false"** attribute on your outside *item* entity. That will indicate to DIH that the document should actually be created for each new instance of the inner *brands* entity.

Comment: Hi Alexandre,Thank you for the answer.I tried rootEntity="false" option. yet i get only 2 results for particular item. Any thing else i can try ?

Comment: What's your ID field? It needs to be unique. If you are using id from parent entity, they will override each other. Maybe you need to template transform the ID as well.

Comment: ID field is default field:id in schema.xml.Can you give me an example.. I will try reindexing with that..

Comment: If your id field is **id** then you are picking the value for that from outer entity. Which means all your inner entities will be competing for that id value. You need to create a composite id or use something like UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory